# How to return the first non-error value in an array?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to return the first non-error value from array input. In the sample below, the output would be `Value A`. In the actual spreadsheet the values would be in an array as a result of the `FILTER` function

---

[image]

`=INDEX(A2:F2,1,MATCH("zzzzzzz",A2:F2,1))` is what I started with but it only returns the last non-error value. I need the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A2:F2,NOT(ISERROR(A2:F2))),,1)
```

**EDIT**:

Simpler to just use the implicit intersection operator `@` (thanks to Harun24HR for the suggestion):

```
=@FILTER(A2:F2,NOT(ISERROR(A2:F2)))
```

Comment: Is your `FILTER` returning the array just an intermediate step? i.e. all you care about is getting `Value A`? If so, my guess is that the original `FILTER` can be modified to just return `Value A`.

Comment: Yea, the final output is `Value A`. Helping someone with a work file and they had a bunch of `IFERROR(VLOOKUP` nested trying to return the first non-error value so I figured a `INDEX` into a filter array would be quicker and easier to modify in the future. This is short and sweet. The equation they had was super long

Comment: Without using `INDEX()` it can be done like `=@FILTER(A2:F2,NOT(ISERROR(A2:F2)))`

Comment: @Harun24HR - yes of course, that's much better.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate not reliant on Dynamic Array functions

```
=INDEX(2:2,1,MATCH(FALSE,ISNA(2:2),0))
```